# Maximal normal subgroup not containing an element

Tags: group-theory

Do you know results about maximal normal subgroup among normal subgroups not containing a given element $x$ ? The problem can be reduce to the case of free groups.

First, such a sugroup exists thanks to Zorn lemma. Secondly, I think that if $x$ is a primitive element, then there is only one maximal normal subgroup among normal subgroups not containing $x$; otherwise, there is not unicity: if $x=[a,b]$, there is a one-to-one correspondance between our normal subgroup and non abelian two-generator groups whose proper quotients are abelian (eg. the dihedral group $D_3$ or the quaternion group $Q_8$).

But I have no idea about how construct such subgroups.

Comment: What is a primitive element?

Comment: A primitive element is an element of a free basis.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you get uniqueness, even in the "primitive" case.

Look at the simple case of $C_2\times C_2$, and consider the maximal subgroups that do not contain $(x,x)$, where $x$ is the nontrivial element: you have $C_2\times\{1\}$ and $\{1\}\times C_2$ as maximal subgroups not containing $(x,x)$.

In the free case, lift the example. Take $F$ free of rank $2$ generated by $x$ and $y$. Then $xy$ is primitive, an element of the basis $x,xy$ (for instance). There are at least two maximal normal subgroups that do not contain $xy$: $N_1=\langle x,y^2,[F,F]\rangle$ and $N_2 = \langle x^2,y,[F,F]\rangle$. As these subgroups have index $2$ in $F$, they are normal and maximal in $F$; they also do not contain $xy$, so they are maximal normal subgroups that do not contain $xy$.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that what you did above was reduced to free groups, yet I can't understand how you use, in the most general case, Zorn's lemma here, as when dealing with a chain (inductively ordered set in the set with partial order) it may be the maximal element you take there is the *whole* group...

Besides the above, there are some groups which have no proper maximal-normal subgroups, e.g. the rationals $\,\Bbb Q\,$ or, for that matter, any other (abelian) divisible group.

I also don't know what a *primitive element* within this context is...perhaps you meant one of the elements in some free basis?

What I can say right now is that *finitely generated* groups always have subgroups which are maximal wrt being normal *and* proper. I once dealed with this while trying to find out something about infinite f.g. simple groups of a rather "sweeter" nature than say Tarski Monsters (e.g., the Higman group which appears in Appendix G of the second book of the english translation, by Hirsch, of Kurosh's "The Theory of Groups". Very nice book, btw).

But even with all the above said, I can't understand why *exactly* could you hope for unicity of a maximal normal group not-containing some primitive element $\,x\,$, but perhaps this is due to my ignorance of what primitive means here.

Comment: Formally, my problem is: Let $F$ be a free group, $x \in F$ and set $\mathcal{N}_x= \{ N \lhd F | x \notin N\}$. What is the maximal elements of $\mathcal{N}_x$ (for inclusion) ? So such an element cannot be the whole group, because it doesn't contain $x$ by definition.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Suppose $\{H_i\}$ is a chain of (normal) subgroups such that each $H_i$ does not contain $x$. Then $\cup H_i$ is a subgroup (easy to verify: nonempty, closed under products and inverses), is normal, and cannot be the whole group: If $\cup H_i = G$, then $x\in \cup H_i$, hence $x\in H_i$ for some $i$; but the $H_i$ are all subgroups that do not contains $x$. While there are no absolute maximal subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}$, if you specify a particular rational, then you *can* find subgroups maximal among those that do not contain $x$. (cont)

Comment: @DonAntonio: (cont) E.g., given $x=\frac{1}{2}$, the subgroup of all rationals which can be written in least terms with odd denominator is maximal among subgroups not containing $\frac{1}{2}$: given any other rational, $\frac{n}{2k}$, $\gcd(2k,n)=1$, we can obtain $\frac{1}{2k}$, and from there $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, thanks for that. I know how to get (normal) subgroups not containing some given fixed element different from the unit using Zorn's lemma. My comment on Q was wrong as there anything is normal and I didn't focus, as I should, on sbgps. not containing some element. It still bugs me though the unicity the OP: in your example this is attainable, but in general? I'm not sure...

Comment: @Seirios, I see your comment and I really don't know if there exists some characterization of such maximal subgroups...